# creating a new arrays from a existing array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I create a new array without doing for each? The new array should be as follows

labels : ["Direct", "Organic Search", "Referral"]

[image: Arrays of an Arrays console pic]

any suggestion using javascript?

Comment: Use `for-loop`/`Array#map` then..Do share your code instead of image...

Comment: `Input.map(function(item){ return item[0]; })`

Comment: without doing for each ,you need to write all steps for create array ! Longer code will be...

Comment: What are these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this without *any* kind of loop, but as you're suggesting, a manual iteration like a `foreach` isn't what you're looking for, indeed.

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the function you need in this case. ("under the hood", it's still a loop)

Here's how you can use `map` to get your desired result:

```js
var myArray = [["a", 1, 2], ["b", 3, 4], ["c", 5, 6]];
var result = myArray.map(function(current){ // For each item in `myArray`
    return current[0];                      // return it's first element.
});                                         // And use that in `result`.

console.log(result)
```

Note that `myArray.map` does not change the value of `myArray`. You'll need to store the returned value from `.map` somewhere.

*If* you don't need to worry about [supporting anything but the latest browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-arrow_functions), you can make this slightly shorter, using ES6:

```js
var myArray = [["a", 1, 2], ["b", 3, 4], ["c", 5, 6]];
var result = myArray.map((c) => c[0]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Don't want `Array.forEach()`? Try using `Array.map` function with ES6 arrow function expression for such case:

```
// supposing arr is your initial array
var labels = arr.map((v) => v[0]);
console.log(labels);  // ["Direct", "Organic Search", "Referral"]
```

Comment: ES6... Much incompatible. OP didn't tag the question with ES6, nor hinted at using it. This answer is in a different language than the question is.

Comment: ES6 ... we believe in future and technical progress

Comment: Envy? No. This answer is incompatible with the question, in it's current form.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I have encountered numerous similar questions on SO which has "successful" ES6 answers(at least, they were accepted by Ops)

Comment: Because the answers conveniently fail to mention compatibility issues, which the OP will find out after using the code for a few weeks. If you're answering a JS question, always explain that you used ES6.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I've added a note, how about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
var arr1 = []; // your main array

var labels = arr1.map(function(item){
   return item[0];
});
```

For reference, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)